# Delphi 7 DCC32 How to specify .exe name?

Tags: delphi, cruisecontrol.net

I've started with a company that uses Cruise Control (CC.Net) to automate their Delphi builds.  I presume the Delphi programs are compiled using the dcc32 command line compiler.
The exe that is created is not cased as required by the users :(

When I compile the program in the Delphi 7 IDE, the target exe is cased correctly.
The .dpr file is cased correctly.
The program name in the .dpr file is cased correctly.

How does dcc32 determine the name of the .exe it creates?  Can it be specified in a compile option?  I've looked at the Embarcadero doco on compile options and don't see a way.

Basically, I have a Delphi 7 project file called ABCDef.dpr

I am expecting ABCDef.exe to be created.
Instead I'm getting AbcDef.exe :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

My recollection is that the compiler uses the letter case of the .dpr file name that is provided on the command line. So you probably compile like this:

```
dcc32 AbcDef.dpr
```

but need to do this:

```
dcc32 ABCDef.dpr
```

Comment: I have just checked and confirm this, if the target executable does not exist than the new one will be created with the same case as specified on the command line. (If it already exists then the existing file name case is preserved.)

Comment: Thanks guys.
I've dug a little more and CC.Net uses NANT to do the actual build.  The relevant (I think) part of the NANT script is:
 <target name="compile">
    <dcc source="PDFMail4.dpr" exeoutput="bin\" dcuoutput="dcus\" build="true"  version="7" mapfile="detailed">
      <unitpath includedelphilib="True"><patternset refid="sources"/></unitpath>
      <defines>
        <define name="USEADO" />
      </defines>
      <compileroptions>
        <option name="O" value="True"/>
        <option name="W" value="True"/>
      </compileroptions>
    </dcc>
  </target>

Comment: Thanks guys.
I've dug a little more and CC.Net uses NANT to do the actual build.  The relevant (I think) part of the NANT script is:
<target name="compile">
    <dcc source="ABCDef.dpr" exeoutput="bin\" dcuoutput="dcus\" build="true"  version="7" mapfile="detailed">
    ...
    </dcc>
</target>

So that looks OK I think.  Certainly when I compile using DCC32 myself I get the exe cased correctly.
In fact the ONLY place I see AbcDef is the folder that contains the project source.  I guess NANT and/or CC.Net must be doing something behind the scenes :(

Comment: Well, I think this is the answer to the dcc32 question